# meaning of where keyword in module declaration

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and reading the book, `Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!`

When the author talks about `where` keyword, he says:

> In imperative programming languages, you would solve this problem by
>   storing the result of a computation in a variable. In this section,
>   you’ll learn how to use Haskell’s where keyword **to store the results
>   of intermediate computations**, which provides similar functionality.

However I saw the `where` keyword also following at the end of a module declaration, and I doubt the "intermediate computations" explanation in this scenario, what's the meaning of the where followed at the end of the module declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo = baz
    where
    baz = 1
    quux = 2
    ...
```

Compare:

```
module Foo 
    where
    baz = 1
    quux = 2
    ...
```

`where` is acting as a syntactic introducer of a scope of definitions.  However, I believe it is just a trick, for we cannot say:

```
let baz = 1
    quux = 2
in module Foo
```

or

```
module Foo
```

(maybe the latter is legal).  I'd like to say that the `module` declaration exports (unless otherwise specified) all symbols in scope at the point of declaration; that would be the most consistent.   But it's false, so we can consider it at best an idiosyncracy of the concrete syntax.  I thought it was weird for a long time too (and upon further reflection answering this question, still do).

Comment: It makes a certain amount of intuitive sense if you think about how you'd fake modules in a low-sugar, diet lambda calculus. The only tool you have is binding variables inside a scope, so the obvious way to implement "modules" is that if module `A` exports `x` and `y`, and module `B` imports `A`, define `A = \m -> m (x, y) where x = foo; y = bar;`, and `B = \(x,y) -> {...}`. The `where` clause now coincides for functions and modules, the "function body" of the module being the export list (implicitly CPS-transformed), and import lists are just arguments to the module.

Comment: Given a slightly larger quantity of credulity, a similar interpretation can almost be forced upon instance declarations; regard the instance head as a pattern matching clause, binding the type parameters in the usual sense, with a completely implicit function body that constructs the class dictionary from appropriately-named definitions in the `where` clause. This analogy is *very* strained, of course, and I admit I like it in part because, when it differs from reality, I often prefer the analogy's version to the actual one...

Answer (score 2):

At its most basic, `where` introduces a new scope. That is its meaning at the top of a module, as well: introduce the scope of module definitions.

Comment: Semantically, defining all the things within a module under `where`, is intuitively strange.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply part of the syntax of naming a module, which is necessary if you want other files to be able to import it. The syntax is

```
module ModuleName (functions and datatypes to export) where
```

The parentheses, which are optional, contain the names of the functions and datatypes you wish to be available to the user of the module. Anything not listed between them will not be imported when the module is imported. If you choose to omit the parentheses, all functions and datatypes will be exported.

Comment: I didn't see why `where` here is necessary, I think they use `where` as part of the syntax must have some good reason.

Comment: It's not really just syntax; the other answer is probably a better explanation. It's basically the same as its use in a function; `x = y where y = 5` means here's a function using y where y is 5. `module A where y = 5` means here's a module called A where this function is declared. Note `where` is also used to introduce typeclasses, instances, and datatypes, as shown [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#where).

Comment: when `where` occurs at the end of a function, the definition of the function is actually in the function body, `where` just applies some restrictions, however in module declaration, there's no `body`, all the things are in the where clause.

Comment: Yeah, they're not exactly the same meaning. I think it's just syntax that helps the compiler (and sometimes a human) understand what's going on. For modules and typeclasses and such it means "I have finished naming this thing and now I will proceed with its definition". They probably used the same word for functions and modules and such because they thought the usage was similar and they couldn't think of a better word. Obviously I'm speculating here, and if you're really curious, I bet there's a thorough explanation in the [haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/).

Comment: To speculate some more, the reason they chose `where` for both these uses is because that's how it would be phrased mathematically. Consider a possible statement in a formal proof: "Let f(x) be a continuous function where ...". Similarly, `instance Functor Maybe where ...` means "Let the datatype `Maybe` be a functor where ...". And within a function: `foo = bar where bar = 12` can be read in a similar fashion. The usage is not exactly the same, but similar enough that the same keyword is used.

Comment: The `where` is just syntax.  There is no real need to have it in a module declaration, it would have worked without it as well.  What is does provide is a way to start a new layout block (which starts after `where`, `let`, `of`, and `do`).  Without the `where` there would have had to be a special case to introduce the new layout block for modules.  Anyway, just syntax, nothing to worry about.